# fstream code not creating a file on my desktop

Tags: c++, file-io

I am new to programming with c++ and have encountered a problem. I am using code blocks IDE with the default compiler that comes with it.

My question is, why isn't a file created on my desktop when I write this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream output;
    output.open("Desktop\\demofile.txt");

    cout << "Now writing data to file" << endl;

    // write four names to file

    output << "Bach" << endl;
    output << "Beethoven" << endl;
    output << "Mozart" << endl;
    output << "Schubert" << endl;

    output.close();
    cout << "Done!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a path starting with "Desktop\\" is going to be the desktop?

Comment: Yet another beginner that adopts the `endl` convention :-(

Answer (score 2):

Because the relative path of the file (the one you are using) starts usually fro  the directory where the program is started (but IDEs can change that).

To be sure of use full path (C:\...)

Answer (score 0):

- Just replace your

  ```
  output.open("Desktop\\demofile.txt");
  ```

  with below line

  ```
  output.open("Desktop//demofile.txt");
  ```
- Means use forward slash instead of backward slash.